# AWS Elastic Beanstalk custom nginx .conf file in the .platform hooks is not created when zip file is uploaded/ deployed

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying a Node JS/ Express JS application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment. I am creating custom nginx config file to change a setting. To do that I created the following file.

{project_root_directory}/.platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/mynginx.conf

```
server {
    client_max_body_size 512M;
}
```

Then to deploy the application as usual, I zip my project and upload the zip in the AWS console. After the environment is updated, I checked the file on the server and it is not there.

[image]

Why the file is not there and how can I fix it?

The following are the details:

Image is Amazon Linux 2 AMI.

I created a .ebextensions folder right inside the root folder with the following files:

00-files.config

```
files:
    "/etc/nginx/conf.d/mynginx.conf" :
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
           client_max_body_size 512M;
```

01-nodecommand.config

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs
    option_name: NodeCommand
    value: "npm start"
```

02-migrationcommand.config

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:nodejs
    option_name: MigrationCommand
    value: "npx sequelize-cli db:migrate"
```

Then again I created .platform/nginx/conf.d/mynginx.config file right inside the root folder with the following content.

```
server {
    client_max_body_size 512M;
}
```

So I have the project structure like this.

[image]

Then I zip the project. Then login to the AWS console and go to the Beanstalk console and upload the zip file there.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that you are using Amazon Linux 2 EB platform, the correct folder should be:

```
{project_root_directory}/.platform/nginx/conf.d/mynginx.conf
```

not

```
{project_root_directory}/.platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/mynginx.conf
```

Update:

Your `mynginx.conf` should be:

```
client_max_body_size 512M;
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that too. It the file just was not there when I upload the zip.

Comment: @WaiYanHein Then maybe you are using Amazon Linux 1. In that case the .platform will not work.

Comment: Nope. I am using Amazon Linux 2.

Comment: @WaiYanHein Can you then update your question with more details, such as exact EB platform version or steps you take to make and deploy your zip? In other words, if I wanted to replicate the issue, what should I do it precisely?

Comment: I have updated to question to include that info. Please, have a look.

Comment: @WaiYanHein I updated the answer. Can you try with the updated `mynginx.conf`?

Comment: Hi, thanks so much. It is all working now. Cheers.

Comment: @WaiYanHein No problem. Glad it worked out :-)

Comment: I tried this. It doesn't work for me :(