# AWS Elastic Beanstalk doesn't find .platform/hooks/postdeploy directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying a spring boot war to a single instance AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment and trying to run a postdeploy script.

I have successfully had .ebextension scripts executed and attempted to follow the same pattern for the .platform/hooks/postdeploy directory but unfortunately EB isn't able to find the directory.

I get the following in the eb-engine.log:

```
[INFO] Executing platform hooks in .platform/hooks/postdeploy/
[INFO] The dir .platform/hooks/postdeploy/ does not exist
[INFO] Finished running scripts in /var/app/current/.platform/hooks/postdeploy
[INFO] Executing cleanup logic
```

I have verified the directory and script are placed inside the WAR file under /WEB-INF/classes:

Directory structure under .platform is .platform/hooks/postdeploy/myscript.sh

The EB environment is an Amazon Linux 2.

Any ideas why EB can't find the .platform/hooks/postdeploy directory? When I cd in /var/app I see a jar file and a Procfile.

Comment: try to use [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73668285/aws-elastic-beanstalk-doesnt-find-platform-hooks-postdeploy-directory) guide lines when you deploy. I think it may help you

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I spent one entire week wondering why my configs are not correctly detected..

As mentioned here [the .platform correct path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69238394/aws-elastic-beanstalk-custom-nginx-conf-file-in-the-platform-hooks-is-not-crea) is `{project_root_directory}/.platform/` and thought I was doing everything fine.

But it need to look like this into your archive ! **The root of the zip must have the .platform into**

In my case it was : `foobar.zip/{project_root_directory}/.platform/`

But it must be :`foobar.zip/.platform/`